# Need advice for selecting EC2 Instance for Rocket.Chat development

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rocket.chat

I need some advice on what type of EC2 instance to use for Rocket.Chat development.

The languages and technologies we will work with are Node.js, Express, mongoDB, etc., using docker.

Team members are about 10 people.
This is not our main work and not all members do work always, and not at the same time.

Projects will be API development ,for example, connecting Zapier to Rocket.Chat, making a chatbot platform through BotHub API, integrating Rocket.Chat with other services.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to go through [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/choosing-the-right-ec2-instance-type-for-your-application/) link to see which Instance Type suits your needs.

In case you are still not sure about it, you can always start with a general-purpose m5.large type. Keep a close eye on CloudWatch metrics to check the CPU Utilization. If you think that the system is unutilized, you can downgrade to a t2 instance and in case the system is overutilized, you can change the instance type to m4.x or c4 instances and so on.

If your application is RAM intensive, a better starting point would be to choose r5/r4 instances.